# Passwordless ssh login to vagrant box from another user

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I have a new user in my vagrant box(trusty64) and I am trying to ssh into it. Instead of logging into `vagrant` user after `vagrant up`, I want to login to my username.

*What I have done so far*

1. Created a user in my guest machine.
2. Created ssh key in my host using `ssh-keygen`
3. Copied the ssh key to the guest using `ssh-copy-id -p 2222 -i shash@127.0.0.1`

*and the part of the Vagrantfile looks like this*

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.username = "shash"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I can use `ssh -p '2222' 'shash@127.0.0.1'` to login directly but when I give `vagrant up` I keep getting the following error

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Any help in sorting out this is really appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: You've not described your actual problem. What happens when actually do what you are wanting to do?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq I have added all the details here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your private key path is pointing to authorized_keys and not the ssh private key. Try: `config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"`